# ORA--00936 missing expression SQL PIVOT

Tags: sql, pivot

i am trying to pivot a query, but keep coming up with the above error, the table i am querying has hundreds of columns and thousands of data pts. I want to use a WHERE clause to limit it to the accts i am interested in.

so basically table i am looking at is something like this:

[image: initial output of query]

What i want the output to be is this:

[image]

i was trying to run this code:

```
SELECT ticker, [1], [2]

FROM 

(SELECT acct_no, pct_mktval FROM POSITION_TABLE WHERE acct_no IN (1,2)

PIVOT(SUM(pct_mktval) FOR acct_no IN ([1], [2]));
```

Effectively i am trying to filter on the accounts that are in the position table, ie in this example exclude acct 3 and then pivot it so these acct numbers become columns with the pct_mktval being displayed inside the table. However i keep coming up with the above error, so i am guessing the logic i have got here is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select ticker,
       sum(case when acct_no = 1 then pct_mktval end) as pct_mkval_1,
       sum(case when acct_no = 2 then pct_mktval end) as pct_mkval_2
from position_table
group by ticker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proper oraclwe syntax

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT acct_no, pct_mktval FROM POSITION_TABLE WHERE acct_no IN (1,2)
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(pct_mktval)
  FOR acct_no IN ([1], [2])
)
```

Comment: thanks this works. if i want to exclude values from one of the columns, say in my example i only want to display data that appears is in acct 1, so if acct 1 holds one of those positions and displays a value then display for all accts/columns, otherwise dont show that row

Comment: Is there anything else you wanted Sam? If it answer you question, you can accept it

Comment: my comment above was a follow on q from the first. i can submit it as a new q though  instead.

Comment: I just didnt understand, give me more details and I will answer